# Cannot convert a::c * to c * in pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is the summary:

```
struct a
{
    struct b{
    } x;

    struct c{
    } y;

};

main(){
    struct a z;
    fun(&z.y)
}
fun(struct c *p){
}
```

getting error in type conversion from a::c * to c * while passing parameters in the function.

My question is whether or not a beginner can participate in stackoverflow, because it seems that my question get more likely to get negative scores.

Original program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void fun(struct c *p);
struct a
{
    struct b
    {
        int i;
        float f;
        char ch;
    } x;


    struct c
    {
        int j;
        float g;
        char ch;
    } y;
};

void main()
{
    int *p;
    struct a z;
    clrscr();
    fun(&z.y);
    printf("\n%d %f %c",z.x.i,z.x.f,z.x.ch) ;
    getch();
}
void fun(struct c *p)
{
    int offset;
    struct b *address;
    offset= (char *) &((struct c *)(& ((struct a*)0)->y)->j)-(char *)((struct a*)0);
    address =(struct b *)((char *)& (p->j)-offset);
    address->i=400;
    address->f=3,14;
    address->char='s';     
}
```

One more question how `0` is is typecasted in `((struct a *)0)`.

Comment: It is a scoping problem.  Define your function parameter as a::c*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because you are using a C++ compiler to compile the C code.

The C code is fine, except that you should add the declaration of the function `fun` before calling it (as what you did in the full program) and use `int main`.

For the second question, `0` in here is not an integer, but a null pointer, `((struct a *)0)` is a null pointer that is cast to type `struct a*`.

Comment: thanks a lot. i missed some point and now i got it what was wrong.